# Tetris shape processing

Tags: processing

I am a newby to processing so sorry for the question. 
However, I am trying to create the following shape:[image]

If I have this shape, I want to use it a couple of times, so I want to create a function. How would I go about programming this? Should I use createShape?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to look at some books, e.g. maybe a good beginner's guide could be this http://www.amazon.co.uk/Windows-Game-Prgrmmng-Dumm-dummies/dp/0764516787

Comment: I think you will like this tutorial: https://processing.org/tutorials/pshape/

Comment: Also, whenever you need a bunch of the same stuff, OOP is the way  to go. Objects (classes) looks complicated, but instead they make things much easier. You may get an idea here: https://processing.org/tutorials/objects/

Answer (score 0):

How you create the shape really depends on how you want to use it.

If you want to use the shape just for display, then sure, having a function that draws it using `createShape()` would work. You might also just use the `rect()` function.

If you want to actually make a Tetris-like game, then you might consider using a 2D array of booleans to represent your grid, that way you can easily check when a row has been completely filled.

If you want something more involved, like multiple versions of these shapes all rotating and colliding with each other, then you might want to look into using a physics engine.

I recommend checking out the [Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/) and just trying something. Try to get it working with the `rect()` function first.